# Apache NameVirtuaHost does not respect ServerName's

Tags: apache, apache2

I have an Apache server configured with several configuration files in which I declare VirtualHost's. However, when I access my server for one of the given ServerName it is not respected and defaults to another one.

My configurations is as followed:

In a ports.conf file I have this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

Then in another file, I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName my.server.com
    ServerAlias other.server.com
    DocumentRoot /home/mys/
    Alias / /home/mys/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mys-error.log
    <Directory /home/mys/>
        Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

In another file I have this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName something.server.com
    ServerAlias else.server.com
    Redirect permanent / https://something.server.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have a configuration on port 443 for something.server.com which works ok

When I call http://my.server.com, I end up on https://something.server.com
All hostnames point to the same IP.

I am running on Apache/2.2.9 (Debian)

Any hint or ideas would be much appreciated. I am not an Apache expert so if I need to provide more info or formulate this in another way, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, actually this is working fine, but because I indicated a Permanent Redirect, Firefox cached the redirect. So nothing wrong in the configuration (although one might say that is probably dangerous to indicate a permanent redirect).